# GatsbyJS - Relative img tag src that point to specific directory/source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm trying to create a static site with GatsbyJS and I need to resolve the `img` tags so that relative *URLs* point to a certain directory, while absolute ones (which start with `http(s)://` work normally).
I've tried making a proper component, but since it's not a *page*, **Graphql** won't run:

```js
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

// Component constants
const absUrlRex = new RegExp(/^https?:\/\//, "i")

// Component
const CustomImg = ({ src, data, ...props }) => {
    let imgSrc = src
    if (!absUrlRex.test(src)) {
        if (null !== data.file) {
            imgSrc = data.file.publicURL
        } else {
            console.log(`Image "${src}" NOT found!`)
        }
    }

    return <img src={imgSrc} {...props} />
}

export default React.memo(
    CustomImg,
    (prev, next) => next.src === prev.src
)

export const query = graphql`
    query($src: String!) {
        file (
            sourceInstanceName: {eq: "images"},
            relativePath: {eq: $src}
        ) {
            publicURL
        }
    }
`
```

---

I've already tried `StaticImage` of "*gatsby-plugin-image*", but the `src` parameter is not a static string, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/page-query/) in a component. That will never work because page queries only works in top-level components (pages), hence the name.

Because you are using a dynamic GraphQL filter parameter (`$src: String!`) using a [static query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/use-static-query/) is not an option (they don't accept dynamic parameters, hence the name) so your only chance is to move the query into a page component and drill down the `file` into the component as a prop.